# How to improve someone's “sprachliche Genauigkeit”?

Tags: vocabulary, speaking

How can I improve someone's "sprachliche Genauigkeit" (these nuances).
For example, in a speaking lesson, someone always makes "the same" grammar mistakes when speaking. Or mispronounces a word, uses the wrong collocations.

How would you correct someone, when you are a teaching assistant?
What is the most efficient way to this?

Comment: Welcome to LL.SE! Are you asking as a teacher (and at what level of education), or as a fellow learner in a lesson, as a tutor or in some other capacity?

Comment: as a teaching assistant for speaking lessons :)

Comment: or better student and soon to be teaching assistant